# Class 'Pusher' not found when installing koel

Tags: composer

I'm trying to install 'koel' on my VPS (Debian Jessie).
I followed this guide (as well as many other guides before)
http://freedif.org/how-to-install-koel-an-opensource-music-streaming-app/

Did a npm install (throwing a incompatibility issue with fsevent:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

)
and them im trying to do a composer install. But i keep running into this error:

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Pusher' not found in /home/streaming/koel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php on line 210


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'Pusher' not found                                 


Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

I googled it but none of the suggested things worked (running composer require throws the same error, thus i cant require pusher/pusher-php-server etc.)

just in case here is the full output in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/jz22Y74u

Answer (score 2):

Running `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server` as suggested by @DerfK was returning the same error message.

I only got it to install correctly by running either
`composer install` or `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`
with the **`--no-scripts`** flag.

After it ran through successfully I was able to continue using composer normally.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the composer dependency file for that project merely "suggests" installing pusher, but it is required for what you are trying to do.  Run

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

which should install it.